# How to get indicative value of the brightness of an image in python?

Tags: python, image, color

Is there a way to obtain an indicative value of the brightness of an image?
I am aware that I can get all the pixels of that image with:

```
myImage = bpy.data.images['My_image']
pxl = (myImage.pixels)
```

I get a list that should contain the above values (I hope I am not wrong about this):

```
pxl[0]# is a R value
pxl[1]# is a G value
pxl[2]# is a B value
pxl[3]# is a Alpha value
pxl[4]# is a R value
... etc.
```

I was thinking that I could average between r, g, b to get a value consistent with brightness, where (theoretically but I'm not sure) the higher than average value should equal a brighter image.

**Now the problems are 2:**

- Traveling to a list of pixels of a 4K image is truly an operation
  that takes too long in a for loop.
- I don't really know how to approach this and the PIL / Image module
  does not exist in the default blender and I'm not going to install
  it.

Would anyone know how to direct me to a trick to get a reliable value to average the brightness of an image?

I was also thinking of traveling or taking only a certain portion of the image, in order to speed up the process, I could also think of taking 1 pixel every 4 or even just an area of 1024x1024 that is 1/4 of an image.
But I have no idea how to do it

**Edit:**

So I managed to make an approximate average of the RGB pixels:

```
img =bpy.data.images['My image']
result = (mean(img.pixels[:][0::4]) + mean(img.pixels[:][1::4]) + mean(img.pixels[:][2::4]))/3
```

Even if I don't know the order of these pixels, if they start at the top left or bottom

This seems to work well and the time is around 4 seconds on a 4K image, but I have ryzen 7 3700x in use and this processor is quite fast, so I think this is still slow.
So I'm thinking, in what order are the pixels in the list, I would like to analyze the image in portions. For example:

- How to analyze only portion 1 (or 2) of an image?

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2:**
So, i found out and if i'm not mistaken, this: `img.pixels[len(img.pixels)//2:]` returns part 1 of the second image and this: `img.pixels[:len(img.pixels)//2]` part 2 of the second image

I did a test with an image as top black and bottom white and the order seems to match

Comment: Be quicker using `pxl = myImage.pixels[:]`  Resizing an image, eg 1/2 width x 1/2 height is a quarter size  copy  to estimate it quicker.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for your helpful suggestion. But I have no idea how to do this

Comment: What exactly do mean by [luminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescence) in this context?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Hi Robert, I corrected luminescence with brightness I apologize for my bad English

Comment: @RobertGützkow  I'm not sure what I have yet to do to get a value that changes (And that is reliable enough) to measure brightness, I need a value that is fairly consistent based on the image that is being used. I don't have much experience in this situation and with python I'm not expert enough to do such a thing without using python add-ons.
I don't even know how to get the right pixels, I don't even know how to navigate to the pixels in a portion of the image, as this operation at the moment seems extremely slow with for or while loops. I am very self-conscious and I don't know what to do

Comment: @RobertGützkow At the moment I am not trying to do anything specific, but it is interesting to be able to understand how to study this, at the moment I would simply like to experiment with any image (jpg, png, etc ...) for example if the image was very bright, I think the average between RGB would be quite high, on the contrary a dark image would give a low RGB average. The problem is that I don't know how to average from the list of pixels, nor how to split an image, or take only sample pixels every 3 (for example)

Comment: @Pastrokkio No problem. So you're interested in the luminance in the photometric / color management sense. In that case you would have to learn about color spaces. You'd need to know the color space of your input (likely sRGB). Humans don't perceive all wavelength of light in the same manner, which is why simply taking the average wouldn't be accurate at all for the brightness.

Comment: Perhaps this is something for @troy_s just to get the color science right. If I'm not mistaken you could convert from [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) back into [CIE XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space)  and then use the Y component which represents the luminance.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I managed to find a small solution, I edited my question, but my problem now is how to get the analysis of an image from a list of pixels, and how to manage any portions.
I really appreciate your interest in this question.